# Thin mesh overlapping when animated

Tags: animation, weight-painting, unity

I am trying to build and animate a dragon in blender. I have built the model and rigged it, the only problem is that when I animate the wings, the bottom faces move higher than the top in some places. It basically looks the same as a Z-fighting problem. I could use a double sided mesh for the wing but I want some thickness to it.

Thank you.

[image: Wing]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: answer provided, please accept it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add thickness to parts of your mesh using the below steps:

- Switch to edit mode then select the vertices you want to add thickness to
- Create a vertex group by pressing the + button on the right of Vertex groups.
- Click the Assign button to assign the selected vertices to the newly created group.

[image: create vertex group]

- Add solidify modifier to your mesh and select the specific vertex group as shown below:

[image: select vertex group]

- Change the thickness value

This modifier will affect only the vertices that are part of that newly created vertex group.

Comment: Okay are you saying rebuild the wings with no thickness, then weight paint, and then use the solidify modifier and it will maintain weights automatically?

Comment: @CoderWolf this will allow you to add thickness to any part of the mesh. No relation to weight paint.

Comment: The wings I've made already have thickness, but by animating them some parts overlap and you see the bottom side move higher than the top. I need some way to make the weight painting extremely consistent or some other method for doing wings. Think of it like a sagging cloth, the webbed parts of the wings need to be able to bend.

Comment: @CoderWolf Please provide your .blend file and add screenshots to your question to be able to help you

Comment: Screenshot added. It's just a thin mesh, when moving the wing some vertices overlap because of I'm assuming inconsistent weights between the top and bottom side of the wing.

Comment: @CoderWolf please provide a .blend file